# Xamarin.iOS :Not able to publish ipa from visual studio to Appstore connect

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, app-store, testflight, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to publish my ipa from visual studio to AppStore. I have set up the profile and certificate for the same and I am able to create an archive . Please refer to the images(sorry for the image quality, screenshot shortcut was not wotking in my macbook so had to take images on phone)After selecting Upload to AppStore, it shows me the details like profile and certificates but earlier it used to show option to publish your app but now it is showing this message

[image: . [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORfJA.jpg)

Comment: Hi , do u add a apple accout to visual studio ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=macos#adding-an-apple-developer-account

Comment: I did on Xcode.

Comment: You mean it can not connect to account in Xcode ?

Comment: Yes. Few days back it was working and it would create an ipa and i would get an option to directly publish it from here to appstorr

Comment: Eh , it's strange and glad it works again . I think it maybe realted to network .

Comment: its still not working !!

Comment: Did you fix this? :)